# Is there an alternative to GCV (generator control voltage) to synchronize frequency sweep measurements?

Tags: oscilloscope, bode-plot, function-generator

A friend is taking a course in electronics engineering and asked me for help reproducing a lab experiment in frequency sweep measurement techniques. Students build a small RC filter and use a function generator to produce a sine wave sweep and show the frequency plot on an oscilloscope using X-Y mode, much like a Bode Plot.

The classroom function generator has a GCV (generator control voltage) output which is fed to the X (ch 1) input of the scope, and apparently produces a 0-5 V DC signal that corresponds to the position of the sweep.

Both my friend and I have more modern, though inexpensive, function generators (e.g. [Rigol DG822](https://beyondmeasure.rigoltech.com/acton/attachment/1579/f-08a5/0/-/-/-/-/DG800_UserGuide_EN.pdf)) that have BNC outputs labeled `Sync/Ext Mode/Trig/FSK` but after extensive consultation with the user guide, no outputs appear to be able to produce a GCV equivalent.

Is there some way to produce a Bode Plot of a basic RC filter using hobby-level oscilloscope and function generator? (Is "GCV" an antiquated term I am not finding an equivalent/replacement for?) I can't think of a way to properly reproduce the lab results without some sort of "sweep position" indicator that the classroom function generator, an older [Leader LGF-1300S](http://manuals.repeater-builder.com/te-files/LEADER/LEADER%20LFG%201300S%20Instruction.pdf), has.

Comment: I discovered [an EEVBlog/Dave Jones video](https://youtu.be/uMH2hGvqhlE) on this topic _after_ asking the question (of course), so I will pursue that method in the meantime.

Comment: Does the scope have an X channel OUTPUT? (a ramp representing the scan waveform ... traditional scopes usually do, digital scopes not so much). That could possibly connect to a frequency control INPUT on the func gen.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I don't believe so but I will check.